# MySQL Statment using a CASE inside of a CONCAT_WS

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this statement that does not error but it does not add in the phone extension the way I was wanting it too.

```
SELECT
      est_contacts.*,
      CONCAT_WS(
        ', ',
        contacts.contact_name,
        contacts.contact_phone,
        (
            CASE contacts.contact_ext WHEN NOT '' THEN CONCAT('x', contacts.contact_ext) END
        ),
        contacts.contact_phone_type
    ) AS contact
    FROM
      est_contacts
    LEFT JOIN
      contacts
    ON
      est_contacts.contact_id = contacts.contact_id
    WHERE
      est_contacts.est_id = 1
```

So Im super new to the `CASE` stuff so this was my first shot at it, it looked like it was going to work and was acting like it, untill i added an Ext to a contact record and it didnt add it even though it was `NOT ''`

Comment: your case has no else/default clause, so if that one match DOESN'T occur, nothing is returned at all.

Comment: thats what i wanted, if it did not have an ext then i wanted it to not even include the ext into the CONCAT_WS i only wanted it to include it if it was preset so the phone number was formatted correctly

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the logic like this:

```
   (CASE WHEN contacts.contact_ext <> '' THEN CONCAT('x', contacts.contact_ext)
    END),
```

Comment: ok, so that worked 100% on the first shot, can you elaborate on your answer a little so i can understand why that works ?

Comment: @AlanDoyle: The `CASE x WHEN v` syntax compares `x` with the value `v`.  In your case, `v` is the expression `NOT ''` and since the empty string is falsey, its logical negation is `1`—therefore your version is equivalent to `CASE contacts.contact_ext WHEN 1 THEN ...`.  If you wanted, you *could* do `CASE contacts.contact_ext WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE ...` instead.

Comment: ahh ok that makes more sense now, Thank you!

Comment: @eggyal Nice call, I thought `not ''` might have been 0 but sqlfiddle confirms it is 1. @AlanDoyle `case x when not ''` is equivalent to `case when x = not ''` or `case when x=1`.

Comment: @JohnD: I think the `NOT` operator first casts its operands to integer, so the empty string becomes `0` whose negation is then `1`.